# <script> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Does 'script' tag with 'src' attribute load the script synchronously ?
F.e. I have the script tag in my code:
`<script src="/js/functions.js"></script>` which defines the function queryString in it.
 
But sometimes (not always) I have the error on this page which says: 
**"The value of the property 'queryString' is null or undefined"**

Comment: Is the file your including being found? Are you getting a 404 error for that particular file's URL?

Comment: where did you put it? head? body start? body end? where is the `queryString` function declared? please provide more info

Comment: I put the script tag to head, function queryString is declared at the beginning of functions.js: function queryString(name, defaultvalue){...}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes a normal script tag will load the js synchronously if you want to load it async then you have to put async in the tag which isn't supported in all browsers only browsers with html 5 support like so

```
<script async src="script/location/file.js"></script>
```

Most likely though and best place to load this js file that depends on the query string is to place in the bottom of the body to allow for all page to load.